# Godaddy, My Tables doesn't appear in Phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using `Godaddy` hosting service. Today, I accessed to `phpmyadmin` to edit some columns but I couldn't see anything in the left column, just `information_schema` in it. But my website **still running** and when I used MySQL® Database Wizard to create a new Database with the name of my old Database it said `The database “...” already exists.`.

Is that phpMyadmin's error? How can I fix it?

Thank for helping me and sorry about my bad English.

Comment: try show databases; there

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it listed nothing except "information_schema".

Comment: Contact goDaddy support. This seems to be off-topic here